# How do I get the row index in a Flatlist in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a Flatlist in my react native app to display an image carousel and I need to pass some sort of counter (index) to each item displayed.

this is my code and I would need an index to be passed to imgCounter parameter

```
<FlatList
   horizontal={true}
   data={data}
   pagingEnabled 
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}           
   renderItem={(itemData) => (             
       <HomeGalleryItem
          id={itemData.item.id}
          imgCounter={???}
          backdrop={itemData.item.backdrop_path}                
          title={itemData.item.title}                
       />
   )}
/>
```

I tried to set a counter as

```
let counter=0
```

and then use it within the Flatlist as

```
imgCounter={counter++}
```

but it doesn't always start from 0, it's kind of random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) for `renderItem`, an index is provided in the callback argument object.

> `renderItem({ item, index, separators });`

You name the parameter `itemData`, so it can be accessed via `itemData.index`.

```
<FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  data={data}
  pagingEnabled 
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}           
  renderItem={(itemData) => (             
    <HomeGalleryItem
      id={itemData.item.id}
      imgCounter={itemData.index}
      backdrop={itemData.item.backdrop_path}                
      title={itemData.item.title}                
    />
  )}
/>
```

If I had to guess about the "jumpiness" of using a counter it could be related to the flatlist's use of virtualization. Flatlist is a convenience wrapper around `VirtualizedList`.

Answer (score 0):

Index is already passed in renderItem.

```
<FlatList
  horizontal={true}
  data={data}
  pagingEnabled 
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}           
  renderItem={(itemData) => (             
    <HomeGalleryItem
      id={itemData.item.id}
      imgCounter={itemData.index}
      backdrop={itemData.item.backdrop_path}                
      title={itemData.item.title}                
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: I had tried that but does not work has it throws the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'itemData.item'). It looks like that if you add the index, cannot identify the itemData.item

Answer (score 0):

I liked using it with **snapToAlignment**, so I can pass a string to position the item, at the **start**, **center** or **end**

```
 <FlatList
    initialNumToRender={1}
    snapToAlignment="start"
    pagingEnabled
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={data}
    renderItem={({item})=>(...)}
    horizontal={true}
  />
```